# Pointer array always generate one even out of index C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

**algo.h**

```
#ifndef _algorithm_
#define _algorithm_

namespace Sorting{
  int *bubble(int *dataPass, int dataSize);
}

#endif
```

**algo.cpp**

```
#include "algorithm.h"

int *Sorting::bubble(int *dataPass, int dataSize){
  for(int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < dataSize; j++){
      cout<<dataPass[j+1]<<" < "<<dataPass[j]<<endl;
      if(dataPass[j+1] < dataPass[j]){
        int tmp = dataPass[j];
        dataPass[j] = dataPass[j+1];
        dataPass[j+1] = tmp;
      }
    }
  }
  return dataPass;
}
```

I want to make a sorting library and I start with bubble sort, apparently I'm facing a problem. For instance I gave the attributes dataPass **array[5] = {7,2,5,8,3}** and the dataSize 5. After this function executed the returned array **1,2,3,5,7** Where did I make it wrong? The array doesn't have 1 but the sorted showed 1, and I figured out the 8 pushed to the index 5th, so my array became 6, I have no idea what is happened.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Be more careful with your array indexing.

Comment: just a little hint: to what element of array index `j + 1` will point if `j = dataSize - 1`?

Comment: Aside from your actual problem, several things: First, you really really want to use std::vector. As in vector<int> Sorting::bubble(const vector<int>& data);. Second, you are aware that you actually change a variable from the outside? That the dataPass pointer actually accesses some variable outside of your function, that one to which it points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your inner loop. You're comparing elements `j` and `j+1` so if dataSize were 10 for example, when `j` is 9 (the last value it could be) you're looking at elements 9 and 10 in your array, but `dataPass[10]` is beyond the bounds of the array. It's a simple fix, just change the loop to be this...

```
for(int j = 0; j < dataSize-1; j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using two loops so it is causing error. size and indexes are not properly defined. be careful with size and index in arrays.

```
for(int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < dataSize-1; j++){
      if(dataPass[j+1] < dataPass[j]){
        int tmp = dataPass[j];
        dataPass[j] = dataPass[j+1];
        dataPass[j+1] = tmp;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.